# How to resolve Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know there are lot of queries already posted related to this issue. But I am still not able to resolve the error.

I am getting,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:100/test/test1.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

To resolve I tried following -

1. I used `--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security`, while launching chrome.exe. (Not working)
2. I put `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');` in php, after `<?php`  tag. (Sometimes it works, but not always).
3. In ajax, `$.ajax({crossDomain:true})` I have included. (Not working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these three lines:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a manual:

http://enable-cors.org/

This presents a variety of options depending your server setup (as well as explain the topic fairly well).

Note that the previous answers are totally correct for PHP... `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');` if you're having problems, remember that you need to send that header *before* you send any body output to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple solution to get this done is you need to add header to server side

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*')
```

In one of my golang API server,I added below header code to allow CORS

```
Response.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Comment: I have already added that line in my php page, still not working.